# Union in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I have a linked access database that is something as follows:

`country year numTest
AF 1990 30
AF 1991 45
AF 1992 50
AF 1993 55
AF 1994 50
BZ 1990 409
BZ 1991 509
BZ 1992 405
BZ 1993 874
CO 1990 0
CO 1991 0
CO 1992 0`

The first query I created was to sum these years together for each country (named testPerformed)

```
SELECT TB_basicInfo.country, Sum(TB_hivTest.hivtest) AS SumOfhivtest
FROM TB_hivTest INNER JOIN TB_basicInfo ON TB_hivTest.ID = TB_basicInfo.ID
GROUP BY TB_basicInfo.country;
```

But now I would like to exclude any country with a sum less than 1. So I created a new query as follows: (named testPerformed > 1)

```
SELECT testPerformed.country, testPerformed.SumOfhivtest
FROM testPerformed
WHERE ((testPerformed.SumOfhivtest)>1);
```

so naturally `CO` would be excluded and this works properly if I run each query separate. However is there a way to combine this into just one query.

I have tired:

```
SELECT TB_basicInfo.country, Sum(TB_hivTest.hivtest) AS SumOfhivtest
FROM TB_hivTest INNER JOIN TB_basicInfo ON TB_hivTest.ID = TB_basicInfo.ID
GROUP BY TB_basicInfo.country
UNION
SELECT TB_basicInfo.country, SumOfhivtest
WHERE SumOfhivtest > 0;
```

but access is not liking this query as it prompts for me to enter the SumOfhivtest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, try this:

```
SELECT TB_basicInfo.country, Sum(TB_hivTest.hivtest) AS SumOfhivtest
FROM TB_hivTest INNER JOIN TB_basicInfo ON TB_hivTest.ID = TB_basicInfo.ID
GROUP BY TB_basicInfo.country
HAVING Sum(TB_hivTest.hivtest) > 0;
```

Comment: Perfecto! I am unfamiliar with `HAVING` do you mind to expand why this works over `UNION`?

Comment: HAVING is like WHERE, except that you use HAVING on aggregate functions during a GROUP BY. UNION allows you to take two separate queries and combine their results into one result set.